# Fetching an API from setlist FM

Tags: node.js, vue.js

Good morning/Afternoon,

I am trying to build out a mini project using Vue and Bootstrap and I am creating a grateful dead website. I am trying to allow the user to be able to search by year to display setlist and limit it to 5 setlist a page and they can scroll to the next set etc.

The roadblock I am facing is when I call the API it does render setlist 20 a page, but it doesn't take into account the year that the user input into the search and always starts with The Dead shows from 2015 and goes to 1995.

I am running Node (first time doing it) and this is what my code looks like:

```
const express = require("express");
const axios = require("axios");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
  })
);
app.get("/api/setlist", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      "https://api.setlist.fm/rest/1.0/artist/6faa7ca7-0d99-4a5e-bfa6-1fd5037520c6/setlists",
      {
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json",
          "x-api-key": "MY TOKEN IS HERE",
        },
        params: req.query,
      }
    );
    res.json(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching Setlist API:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Error fetching data");
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

On the front end inside the component that displays the setlist I have:

```
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "About",
  data() {
    return {
      search: {
        year: null,
        state: "",
        city: "",
        song: "",
      },
      searchResults: [],
      error: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async searchByYear() {
      console.log(
        "API URL:",
        `http://localhost:3000/api/setlist?year=${this.search.year}`
      );

      try {
        const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/setlist", {
          params: {
            year: this.search.year,
            // state: this.search.state,
            // city: this.search.city,
            // song: this.search.song,
          },
        });
        console.log("Received Data from Server:", response.data); // Add this line to log the data received from the server

        this.searchResults = response.data.setlist;
        console.log("Updated searchResults:", this.searchResults);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching search results:", error);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Any direction or guidance on how to get past this roadblock would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That endpoint only accepts two parameters according to the docs, artist ID and page number.  There are no other filter options.

There is another endpoint [/search/setlists](https://api.setlist.fm/docs/1.0/ui/index.html#//1.0/search/setlists) with a lot more parameters, including artist ID and year. Use that one.

```js
const { data } = await axios.get(
  "https://api.setlist.fm/rest/1.0/search/setlists",
    {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "x-api-key": "MY TOKEN IS HERE",
      },
    params: { 
      "artistMbid": "6faa7ca7-0d99-4a5e-bfa6-1fd5037520c6", 
      ...req.query
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, so new to this sometimes I struggle with the docs!